# Improving an array check method

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following method that receives an array of digits from a user and an array of digits from the computer.   It then checks to see if the digits the user entered are correct and in the right position as the computer generated number.  For example if the user enters 2341 and the computer number is 2358, the result array would be 2200 (two correct numbers in the right position, two wrong numbers).  The method works just fine, I was wondering how to make it more concise and cut back on the code.

```
@Override
public String checkValues(String [] userInput, int [] computerNumber)
  {
   int flag = 0;
   String [] validate = {""};
   //Results can be put inside an int array 
   //int  [] results = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(userInput[i]) == computerNumber[j]) {
               if (i==j) {
                   validate[0]+="2";
                   flag++ ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(userInput[i])==computerNumber[j] && (i!=j)) {
                validate[0]+="1";
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
switch(flag) 
 {
     case 0: validate[0]+="0000"; break;
     case 1: validate[0]+="000"; break;
     case 2: validate[0]+="00"; break;
     case 3: validate[0]+="0"; break;
 }
    return validate[0];
}
```

*****Full class***

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mastermind2;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
/**
 *
 * @author sarth
 */
public class MM implements MasterMindInterface {

    String[][] grid = new String[10][4];

    /*
    * DrawGame Void method draws the grid 
    */
    @Override
    public void drawGame() 
    {
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("|  " + "X" + "  |  " + "X" + "  |  " + "X" + "  |  " + "X" + "  |");
        System.out.println("------------------------    -----");

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("|  "  +  "  |  " + "  |  " + "  |  "  +  "  |==|    |    |");  

            System.out.println("------------------------    -----");
        }
    }//End of Draw Game method

    /*
    * New Game method asks the user to type in 4 unique numbers
    *Returns the numbers at the end
    *@Param unserInput - an array where the 4 numbers entered by the user are stored
    */
    @Override
    public int [] newGame()
    {
        //Regular expression so only numbers are entered
        String match = "[0-9]+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(match);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] userInput = new int[4];
        System.out.println("Please enter a unique 4 digit number with spaces in between");
        try 
        {
        String userNum = input.nextLine();

        Matcher m = p.matcher(userNum);

        if (m.find())
        {
        String [] tempNum  = userNum.split(" ");
        userInput[0] = Integer.parseInt(tempNum[0]);
        userInput[1] = Integer.parseInt(tempNum[1]);
        userInput[2] = Integer.parseInt(tempNum[2]);
        userInput[3] = Integer.parseInt(tempNum[3]);
        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry by user nothing was found");    
        }
        }
         catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){}
        return userInput;
    }

    /*
    * Method generates 4 digit random number between 1 and 8
    */   
    @Override
    public int [] generateCompNum()
    {
    int [] random = new int [4];
    List<Integer>compNumber = new ArrayList<>(4);
    //add numbers 1 to 8 in the list
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) 
    {
        compNumber.add(i);
    }
       //Shuffle the list
       Collections.shuffle(compNumber);   
       //Put for random numbers into the secondary list after shuffle
       for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++)
       {
       random[i] = compNumber.get(i);
       }

      //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(random));
       return random;
    }

    @Override
    public String checkValues(String [] userInput, int [] computerNumber)
    {
   int flag = 0;
   String [] validate = {""};
   //Results can be put inside an int array 
   //int  [] results = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(userInput[i]) == computerNumber[j]) {
               if (i==j) {
                   validate[0]+="2";
                   flag++ ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(userInput[i])==computerNumber[j] && (i!=j)) {
                validate[0]+="1";
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
 switch(flag) 
 {
     case 0: validate[0]+="0000"; break;
     case 1: validate[0]+="000"; break;
     case 2: validate[0]+="00"; break;
     case 3: validate[0]+="0"; break;
 }
    return validate[0];
    }//End of checkValue method

    @Override
        public void updateGame(String[][] resultArray,String[] clueArray) {
        System.out.println(" ---------------");
        System.out.println("| "+"X"+" | "+"X"+" | "+"X"+" | "+"X"+" | ");

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println(" ---------------"+"     ----");
        System.out.println("| "+resultArray[i][0]+" | "+resultArray[i][1]+" | "+resultArray[i][2]+" | "+resultArray[i][3]+" | "+"=="+"|"+clueArray[i]+"|");
        }
        System.out.println(" ---------------"+"     ----");
        System.out.println("");

    }


    public void finalUpdateGame(String [][] resultArray, String[] clueArray, int [] secretCodeArray)
    {
        System.out.println(" ---------------");
        System.out.println("| "+secretCodeArray[0]+" | "+secretCodeArray[1]+" | "+secretCodeArray[2]+" | "+secretCodeArray[3]+" | ");

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(" ---------------"+"     ----");
            System.out.println("| "+resultArray[i][0]+" | "+resultArray[i][1]+" | "+resultArray[i][2]+" | "+resultArray[i][3]+" | "+"=="+"|"+clueArray[i]+"|");
        }

        System.out.println(" ---------------"+"     ----");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

****Main Method*****

```
package mastermind2;

/**
 *
 * @author sarth
 */
public class MasterMind2 {


    public static String [][] board = new String[10][4];
    public static int [] tempComp;
    public static  String [] computerNum = new String[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      //Calling the MM class with all methods
      MM mastermind = new MM();
     //Initialize the board
      for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j< 4; j++) {
              board[i][j] = "";
          }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
        computerNum[i]= "    ";
      }
     //Call the draw game method
      mastermind.drawGame();
      tempComp = mastermind.generateCompNum();
        //give user 10 
        for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            int temp[] = mastermind.newGame();
                for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++) 
                {
                    board[i][j]+=temp[j];
                }
                computerNum[i] = mastermind.checkValues(board[i], tempComp);

                if(Integer.parseInt(computerNum[i])==2222)
                {
                    mastermind.finalUpdateGame(board, computerNum, tempComp);
                }
                else 
                {
                    mastermind.updateGame(board,computerNum);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

There's an interface as well, but I guess I don't have to post that :P

So the user has 10 tries to guess the 4 digits generated by the computer.  The computer generates a unique 4 digit number between 1 and 8.  If the user guess the correct number the game ends, if the comp number is 2351 and user enters 8743 the result array displays 0000, if numbers are right but in the wrong position it shows 1111, if they are all correct the result array shows 2222

Comment: Better ask at [codereview.SE]

Comment: I had no idea that existed!  sorry

Comment: Before you ask at Code Review, you should create a complete class with a main method and several example inputs and outputs. And, most importantly, describe the purpose of the method better because it's not very clear. It looks like it could return up to 20 digits: 4 from the first loop plus 4x4 from the second loop.

Comment: Your explanation is still not clear. You say the computer generates a unique 4 digit number between 1 and 8. Then you say it can generate 0000, 1111 or 2222. Those numbers are not between 1 and 8. Also, what do you mean by "unique"?

Comment: 0000 1111 or 2222 are possible result after the user digits and the computer digits are compared.   Example:  Comp number 2 3 4 1, user enters 4 1 7 8, results would be 1100 as the user entered two right numbers but they are in the wrong position.  Sorry being unclear earlier.  this is basically mastermind game with numbers

Comment: So for every digit in your guess, the corresponding digit in the answer is 0, 1 or 2, where 0 means the guessed digit is absent from the hidden number, 1 means it's present but in the wrong position, and 2 means it's present and in the correct position. Have I understood right? (The last time I played MasterMind, I was about 10 years old, so excuse my bad memory.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that user input 2458 against 2358 probably should return 3033.
So at least one first has to count the matches:

```
public String checkValues(String[] userInput, int[] computerNumber) {
    int right = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < computerNumber.length; ++i) {
        if (i >= userInput.length) {
            ++wrong;
        } else if (userInput[i].equals(computerNumber[i])) {
            ++right;
        } else {
            ++wrong;
        }
    }
    //Would have been nice: return new int[] { right, wrong };
    String rightText = String.valueOf(right);
    ...
}
```

Still a bit to do.

Comment: interesting.  I will update the main topic with the full class and main method like another person suggested

Comment: Yes CodeReview is nice, but prepare a bit, autoformat your code and such.

Comment: I added the full class and the main with full description